# How to Run a.out Using exec() Command

Tags: c

How do I run an executable file like `a.out` using the standard C library functions `exec()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what documentation is for. Please don't ask questions without showing real effort put into them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever is `exec`, it is not C standard.

If you are speaking about `execve` (POSIX), look at the documentation.

```
int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

So:

```
#include <unistd.h>

char *args[] = { "./a.out", /* other arguments */, NULL };

execve("a.out", args, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The exec function family's documentation can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html)(Scroll down to the bottom for exapmles). But if you want to run an external program from within your own you could also use [system()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html). I would not recommend using it because it is not very secure. But if you are just playing around with C you should be fine using it.